# Compare-and-swap in etcd v3?

Tags: go, etcd, etcd3

I'm trying to do a compare-and-store operation on a given key using etcd's Go client for the `v3` API. Seeing that `--swap-with-value` seems to be gone from `etcdctl put`, I suspect there's no corresponding method or argument in the client library either. Thus, I'm attempting my own implementation:

```
res, err := etcdv3.KV.Txn(context.Background()).If(
    etcdv3.Compare(etcdv3.ModRevision(c.path), "=", c.modRevision),
).Then(
    etcdv3.OpPut(c.path, string(data)),
    etcdv3.OpGet(c.path),
).Commit()

if err != nil {
    return err
}
if !res.Succeeded {
    return fmt.Errorf("A newer revision exists.")
}

// Return the current `ModRevision` on success.
return res.Responses[1].GetResponseRange().Kvs[0].ModRevision
```

However, Go refuses to compile with this message:

```
main.go:55: not enough arguments in call to method expression clientv3.KV.Txn
    have ("context".Context)
    want (clientv3.KV, "github.com/miguel/myproject/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context".Context)
```

What's wrong with this approach? Why does Go refuse to compile this snippet?

**Edit:** Thanks to JimB I found out that `etcdv3` is importing the old `golang/x/net/context` packages. I switched the `import` statements, but I still get something similar:

```
main.go:55: not enough arguments in call to method expression clientv3.KV.Txn
    have ("github.com/miguel/myproject/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context".Context)
    want (clientv3.KV, "github.com/miguel/myproject/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context".Context)
```

Comment: You're using the old `golang.org/x/net/context` package when you should be using the `context` package in the std library.

Comment: It's not me, in fact, but `etcd` :-( I tried switching to the old package and I got a similar error (please check my edit).

Comment: That's because you're using a "method expression", which means that you're calling a method without the implied receiver. I'm not familiar with their client package, and I'm not sure why the client has a `KV` field at all, but the Txn example under [`KV`](https://godoc.org/github.com/coreos/etcd/clientv3#KV) at least shows you need to need to use `NewKv` to be able to call `Txn`

Comment: Thank you very much JimB. I wish I could approve your comment as an answer. It works now :-)

Comment: no prob. I was going to try and look to see _what_ the KV field is to explain the behavior when I have a moment. If someone more familiar with that package know, they can certainly write up a complete answer first.